# Get BIGINT value from sqllite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I use this module https://www.npmjs.org/package/sqlite3 for work with sqlite3.

I need to save/load big integers from database, but i can't, because after number saved result is different.

My code:

```
var sql = require('sqlite3');

var db = new sql.Database(':memory:');

 db.serialize(function() {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info BIGINT)");

    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES ($value)");
    stmt.bind({
       $value : "1000000000012312312"
    });

    stmt.run(function (err) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
       } else {
         db.all("SELECT info FROM lorem", function (err, r) {
             if (err) {
                console.log(err);
             } else {
                 console.log(r)
             }
         })
       }
    });
```

Result:

```
  [ { info: 1000000000012312300 } ]
```

So, result is different. I saved 1000000000012312312, i got 1000000000012312300.

I think i need to convert result number from sqlite to string, but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does not have big integers, so large numbers must be approximated with floating-point numbers.

To convert a value into a string, use a [CAST expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr):

```sql
SELECT CAST(info AS TEXT) AS info FROM lorem
```